# searching json file for key angular 2+

Tags: json, angular, search, key, mapping

On my website I would like to verify the input a user does when he puts in the 3 letter code or 2 letter code. It should return the value of the key.
So if he types in "BTC" it should return "bitcoin" and show it next to the input.
I found this example, but it seems quite complicated for what I want: https://github.com/ghiden/angucomplete-alt and it is angularjs

```html
      Search three lettercode coin: <input ng-model="query">
```

```html
{

  "42": "42 Coin",

  "365": "365Coin",

  "404": "404Coin",

  "611": "SixEleven",

  "808": "808"
  
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to probably do this:
- Check form input on each type

```
oninput="checkInput($event)"
```

Then you can see if it matches any of the keys:

```
function outputData(value) {
    alert(value);
}

function checkInput(event) {
    // Check event.target.value with either if cases or a switch statement and 
    //then trigger the function that outputs the key value.
    if (event.target.value === 'BTC') {
        outputData('Bitcon');
    } else if (event.target.value === '....') {
        .....
    }
}
```